# Website logout time issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, web-config, session-timeout

My website automatically logout after 15 mins . I want to set the timeout in two hours or one day .

See below my Webconfig code

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login"  protection="All"  slidingExpiration="false" timeout="3600"/> 
    </authentication>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false"  timeout="3600"></sessionState>
```

I search more answers in  google and i put  lot of minutes in timeout property . But it's not working. Any time logout after just 15 mins only  .

Can you help me ? How ca i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

May be your application is recycled and new machine key is assigned automatically. You may need to assign machine key in you web.config. You may generate machine key from [here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="MACHINEKEY"
                decryptionKey="decrypt key here" 
                validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```